# concurrent.futures: how to submit task and process Futures in 2 separate Threads?

Tags: python, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to improving the interactive output of small CLI program walking a directory to process files, and using a [Rich](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/latest/progress.html) progress bar to display the progression of the tasks.

At the moment, I'm doing this in 2 steps:

- `pool.submit()` all the tasks
- `for future in as_completed(xxxx)` wait for the next future available.

The problem is that the first step (`pool.submit`) might take some time (since I'm walking the directory), and the UI isn't updated, even though futures have already been available.

So, I tried to come up with a Thread that would submit on my pool, while the main thread would wait on the next Future and update the UI:

```py
"""
Usage: walker.py [options] <file/directory>...

Options:
    -r --recursive                  Walk directories recursively
    -w WORKERS --workers=WORKERS    Specify the number of process pool workers [default: 4]
    -d --debug                      Enable debug output
    -h --help                       Display this message
"""
import os
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures._base import as_completed
from concurrent.futures.process import ProcessPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path
from random import randint
from typing import List

from docopt import docopt
from rich.console import Console
from rich.progress import BarColumn, Progress, TextColumn


def walk_filepath_list(filepath_list: List[Path], recursive: bool = False):
    for path in filepath_list:
        if path.is_dir() and not path.is_symlink():
            if recursive:
                for f in os.scandir(path):
                    yield from walk_filepath_list([Path(f)], recursive)
            else:
                yield from (Path(f) for f in os.scandir(path))
        elif path.is_file():
            yield path


def process_task(filepath):
    rand = randint(0, 1)
    time.sleep(rand)


def thread_submit(pool, filepath_list, recursive, future_to_filepath):
    for filepath in walk_filepath_list(filepath_list, recursive):
        future = pool.submit(process_task, filepath)
        # update shared dict
        future_to_filepath[future] = filepath


def main(args):
    filepath_list = [Path(entry) for entry in args["<file/directory>"]]
    debug = args["--debug"]
    workers = int(args["--workers"])
    recursive = args["--recursive"]

    console = Console()

    process_bar = Progress(
        TextColumn("[bold blue]Processing...", justify="left"),
        BarColumn(bar_width=None),
        "{task.completed}/{task.total}",
        "•",
        "[progress.percentage]{task.percentage:>3.1f}%",
        console=console,
    )
    process_bar.start()

    # we need to consume the iterator once to get the total
    # for the progress bar
    count = sum(1 for i in walk_filepath_list(filepath_list, recursive))
    task_process_bar = process_bar.add_task("Main task", total=count)
    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=workers) as pool:
        # shared dict between threads
        # [Future] => [filepath]
        future_to_filepath = {}
        submit_thread = threading.Thread(
            target=thread_submit, args=(pool, filepath_list, recursive, future_to_filepath)
        )
        submit_thread.start()
        while len(future_to_filepath.keys()) != count:
            for future in as_completed(future_to_filepath):
                filepath = future_to_filepath[future]
                # print(f"processing future: {filepath}")
                try:
                    data = future.result()
                finally:
                    # update progress bar
                    process_bar.update(task_process_bar, advance=1)
    process_bar.stop()


def entrypoint():
    args = docopt(__doc__)
    main(args)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    entrypoint()
```

However, the progress bar isn't updated as expected.
Worse, there are cases where the processing doesn't seem to end.

- is it a race conditions when I update my dict `future_to_filepath` ?
- how would you go to have a **submit** thread and a **process_results** thread with `concurrent.futures` ?

Thank you SO !

Comment: I don't understand why you needed a separate thread to create your `Future` instances. Perhaps you should first `join` that thread before proceeding with the `while len(future_to_filepath.keys()) != count:` statement. That could be a race condition. That test also does not make much sense. The length of the dictionary's keys goes from 0 before the thread runs to the total number of `Future` instances created by calls to `submit` in the thread (`count`?) but then never changes even as the `Future` instances complete. I just don't get it.

Comment: Are you under the assumption that creating the futures via `submit` is a timely operation whose processing and thus needs to be done in a separate thread? I wouldn't be too concerned about that. Once all the futures have been created by the thread, it appears your test `while len(future_to_filepath.keys()) != count:` will be `False` and you will prematurely break out of the loop. It just seems very non-deterministic.

Comment: Hi,
If I join the thread before processing the future, then there is no point having a thread at all.
The point is to refresh the progress bar as soon as possible.

Creating the Future via `pool.submit` is cheap, however walking the filesystem is not cheap, therefore the need to do it in a thread.

Answer (score 0):

See my comments to your question and then:

Change:

```
submit_thread = threading.Thread(
    target=thread_submit, args=(pool, filepath_list, recursive, future_to_filepath)
)
submit_thread.start()
```

To:

```
thread_submit(pool, filepath_list, recursive, future_to_filepath)
```

(a change to this function name, since it is no longer running as a separate thread, would be a good thing -- how about `create_futures`?)

And remove the outer loop:

```
while len(future_to_filepath.keys()) != count:
```

Finally, it is not clear what your real `process_task` will do with the file but it certainly seems possible that it will be I/O bound. In that case, you might benefit instead from using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class, easily substitutable for the `ProcessPoolExecutor` class, in which case you should consider specifying a much larger number of workers, possibly equal to `count`. Since your current `process_task` is doing nothing much more than sleeping, it would probably profit from threading with the larger number of workers.

**Update**

<s>One thing you can do to reduce the time it takes to run `walk_filepath_list`</s>  is to modify the function to be passed a single path to walk rather than a list and to process each path that was in the original list concurrently in separate threads. In the code below I am using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` `map` function for convenience which really requires that the arguments to the (newly renamed) `walk_filepath` function be reversed so that I can use `functools.partial` to "harcode" the first argument, `recursive`, for all the calls:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial


def walk_filepath(recursive: bool = False, path: Path = None):
    if path.is_dir() and not path.is_symlink():
        if recursive:
            for f in os.scandir(path):
                yield from walk_filepath(recursive, Path(f))
        else:
            yield from (Path(f) for f in os.scandir(path))
    elif path.is_file():
        yield path

def walker(recursive, path):
    return list(walk_filepath(recursive, path))


def thread_submit(pool, filepath_list, recursive, future_to_filepath):
    n_workers = len(filepath_list)
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=n_workers) as executor:
        filepath_lists = executor.map(partial(walker, recursive), filepath_list)
        for filepath_list in filepath_lists:
            for filepath in filepath_list:
                future = pool.submit(process_task, filepath)
                # update shared dict
                future_to_filepath[future] = filepath
```

**Update 2**

A benchmark of the above code reveals that it does not save time (perhaps if the directories were on different physical drives?).

Comment: Hi and thank you for your answer.
Your first suggestion is to remove the thread, which is the solution that I have right now, and that I want to improve.

The problem that I'm facing is that `walk_filepath_list` function can take a long time to complete. And while it is processing, I cannot refresh the UI with the non-threaded approach.

Regarding the `while` condition, yes, it wasn't useful, I removed it.

Regarding the `ProcessPoolExecutor`, my tasks are CPU intensive, and not IO bound, so I need multiples processes to crunch the tasks.

Comment: Actually, I did a benchmark and it does not save any time.